# Technology for Asp.net MVC online game

Tags: asp.net-mvc, websocket

I am planing to make online game like chess on asp.net. What technologies can you recommend to use for online game? Node.js? HTML5 WebSockets or something else.

Comment: You would be better of constraining your question to a particular aspect of game development. It sounds like you are concerned with handling a lot of connections.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) - async library for .NET to help build real-time, multi-user interactive web applications.